# I am using MAMP and i can open my website only if my filename is index.html.

Tags: php, html, mamp

If I name it index.php, it gives error

Error :

The localhost page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

I already checked the conf files but I dont understand what to edit to just make my index.php appear on the browser.

The moment i change my index.php filename to inex.html, it works correctly except the php form functionalities ofcourse.

How do I deal with this ?

Comment: That usually means there is a serious error in that PHP script. If you name the file with an extension other than `.php` the PHP code will not get executed and therefore you dont get the 500 error

Comment: What is your code in `index.php` file? It seems a script error.

Comment: Sorry if i sound stupid, but i am completely new at web developement.
But even if the php script is incorrect, shouldn't it still display the rest of the webpage minus the php functionality ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly it worked after i managed to fix my php script. :)